# Spring polling + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring-integration

Scenario : poll the database every 'n' seconds and retrieve list. Do some internal business validations.If validations are success only, send the retrieved list to an external system.Receive an acknowledgment response from that system(After receiving this,poller should send next list).Then perform some business operations like calling other systems where polling is not needed.
can any one tell me how this scenario can be handled?

poller.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
 xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.1.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd">

 <import resource="persistence-config.xml" />

 <int:channel id="inchannel">
 </int:channel>

 <int:channel id="outchannel">
 <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/> 
  </int:channel>
  
 <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="2"/>


 <bean id="poller" class="main.java.com.as.poller.PollerService" />


 <int:service-activator input-channel="inchannel"
  output-channel="outchannel" ref="poller" method="sendMessage" />


 <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
  query="select loyalty_id from TBL_RECEIPT where  receipt_status=0"
  channel="inchannel" data-source="dataSource" max-rows-per-poll="1">
  <int:poller fixed-rate="5000">
  </int:poller>
 </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>


</beans>
```

```html
ackage main.java.com.as.poller;
 

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


 @Component
public class PollerService{
    public void sendMessage()
    {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "AS-servlet.xml");
     DirectChannel directChannel = (DirectChannel) context.getBean("inchannel");
    }

     
}
```

I added a direct channel to poll the DB.Also added an executer channel..But i am getting the exception

```html
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'executerChannel' while setting bean property 'outputChannel'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'executerChannel' is defined
rg.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
```

Can anyone please help with this...I have created only **PollerService.java** and dont have any idea to implement **executer channel and task executer**

Comment: This question is really too broad; read the [Spring Integration Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/). When you understand the basic concepts; read the section on JPA Support. There are [lots of samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) including at least one that uses JPA with hibernate. When you've done all that, come back here if you have _specific_ questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<poller>` does that for you by default if you use `fixed-delay` option and your downstream flow is single threaded (only `DirectChannel`s). In that case the next polling task (in your case reading DB using JPA) won't be started until the finish of previous one and some time like `fixed-delay`. See `PeriodicTrigger`, BTW.

Regarding your "Then perform some business operations". You should just make the next channel after "Receive an acknowledgment response" as an `ExecutorChannel` to free the polling Thread for the next poll.

You should really read more in the Spring Integration Reference Manual and especially about the [Poller](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-adapter-namespace-inbound).

Comment: ??? Not sure what the problem you have, but we can't help you in coding you should demonstrate us some PoC and point out where is a stuck. Otherwise it sounds like: please, write the application for me!

Comment: Well, I said you how it can be handled: only using `fixed-delay` and `DirectChannels` s. You should only shift the reply for that external service into the `ExecutorChannel` to perform the next logic and free the current Thread for the next poll task to retrieve a new List of entities by Hibernate. What else you would like to hear ?

Comment: :-). No, I really want to help you and it would be great to hear from your side "Hooray, it works!". But want I don't like when people don't try to write code themselves but ask for it from us. So, if you have some code to follow up, we can try to polish it a bit according to your requirements.

Comment: ...i have edited the question.can you please go through it..I have added direct channel and executer channel as said by you..